# Magento 2.1 :- "Node "argument" required for this type. When run admin controller

Tags: layout, magento-2.1, admin-controller

When I run admin controller for test/index/index. I got below error.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:39:"Node "argument" required for this type.";i:1;s:4679:"#0 mage2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Argument\Interpreter\ConfigurableObject->evaluate(Array)
#1 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#2 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(43): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#3 mage2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#4 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#5 mage2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(188): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#6 mage2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(191): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->evaluateComponentArguments(Array)
#7 mage2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(191): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->evaluateComponentArguments(Array)
#8 mage2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(172): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->evaluateComponentArguments(Array)
#9 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(144): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('test...')
#10 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('test...', NULL, Array)
#11 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'test...', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#12 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#13 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#14 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#15 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#16 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#17 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#18 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(207): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#19 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(227): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild()
#20 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#21 mage2/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#22 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#23 mage2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#24 mage2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#25 {main}";s:3:"url";s:133:"mage2/admin/test/index/index/key/d539cbf6ddb14805d8a0a52ffd961e6b66c5ae5f71bd78f241fc85ba71b85aa8/";s:11:"script_name";s:38:"mage2/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error.
I create some new file as below.

1. app/code/Vendor/Test/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php
2. app/code/Vendor/Test/view/adminhtml/layout/test_index_index.xml
3. app/code/Vendor/Test/view/adminhtml/ui_component/test_index_grid.xml

Because, in xml file can't load properly and also some hidden character in above three files.
Now all functionality is working perfect for my module.